Climb down from a bus meaning
From The New York Trilogy, Paul Auster.

An hour later, as he climbed from the number 4 bus at 70th Street and Fifth Avenue, he still had not answered the question.

I don't get "climb from a bus".

He exited the bus.  Getting off a bus usually requires descending a few steps, hence “climbed from.”

In some places the platform of the bus is quite high up so there are steps you need to climb up or down to get on and off it. And handles to help too. If you come from somewhere where the bus is much lower and you just walk on and off "climb from the bus" will sound utterly weird. (from the bus to where?)

What don't you get? Please read this before asking a question.

The phrase as quoted does seem a little 'off' for me. It should probably be '...as he climbed down from the bus...'. Or better '...as he got off the bus' or '...as he got on the bus' (depending on context).

@Mitch Agree that "climb from" sounds a bit strange without specifying the "to" or some other preposition, since it typically implies moving up. One could "climb from tree to tree", or "climb down from a tree", but to simply "climb from a tree" sounds incomplete. It sounds like you'd be climbing up some other object, starting from the tree.

"Got off the bus" is a lot more common, but "climbed from the bus" is represented in this NGram graph. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=climbed+from+the+bus%2Cgot+off+the+bus&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comments are correct - in this instance it means to get off the bus. Since buses usually have one or two steps, it is like climbing up/down stairs - just a word for going which includes upward/downward motion

Where I come from buses don't have one or two steps (unless you go up to the top floor of a double;e-decker). You just walk on and off the bus. Or ride onto it in your wheelchair. Or get pushed onto it in your buggy.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore. That's not how it used to be.  In many parts of the world you still have steps.  You need them if the buses are stopping next to a footpath.  Otherwise they will be riding on toy tyres.

@Araucaria-Nothereanymore.you can clearly see the steps in this photo https://www.busesforsale.com/buses/9665/9665-2.jpg?v=1617126684

@RohitGupta JavaLatte Yes, I know. (See my comment under the Q) I’m just hinting at the fact that the reason it’s confusing for some learners is that in many places buses don’t have stairs!
